# How can you measure the polarization of a single-photon without destroying it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, polarization

In Quantum Key Distribution, namely the [BB84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BB84) protocol, Alice creates single-photons in the horizontal/vertical basis or the (45 degree rotated) diagonal basis which she then sends to Bob over a transmission line.

Now if an eavesdropper Eve that has the ability to measure the polarization of the photons is intercepting this transmission line, she can try to figure out the secret key that Alice is trying to send to Bob. But how can Eve measure the polarization of a single-photon without destroying it?

In videos like this https://youtu.be/uiiaAJ3c6dM?t=171 it looks like the polarization filters are able to measure the polarization of the photons without destroying them. But is that feasible in the real world? I mean if I use a vertical polarization filter to measure a horizontally polarized photon, that photon will be absorbed/destroyed by my filter.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to know the polarization of light experimentally, you need to make a series of measurements in different bases/directions using a different filter each time. Each measurement indeed will destroy a single photon, so in order to fully know the polarization of light you need to measure an ensemble/collection of photons. I think that this is what the linked video is trying to explain: Eve has to choose one basis in which to measure the single photon (and then create a new photon of the measured polarization to send to Bob). However, if Eve chose the wrong basis in which to measure the photon's polarization, she will send Bob a photon of the wrong polarization. The video describes, however, that Alice can send a classical message to Bob to tell him which basis to measure the photon's polarization in.